# Grouping and only returning the most recent record in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table `AppointmentStatusHistory` in the following format:

```
AppointmentId   AppointmentStatusId   Date
========================================================
1               1                     2/1/2012 (2nd January)
1               2                     2/2/2012 (2nd February)
```

I currently run a query against this to return the **'most recent' status** for the appointment within a given timeframe.

**My LINQ Query**

```
items = (from t1 in db.AppointmentStatusHistories
         from t2 in db.TaskAppointments
                      .Where(o => (o.ID == t1.AppointmentId))
         from t3 in db.Tasks
                      .Where(o => (o.Task_ID == t2.Parent_Task_ID))
         where t1.Timestamp >= first && t1.Timestamp <= last
            && t3.Creator == user
         group t1 by t1.AppointmentId into grp
         select new UserAppointmentTargetModel
         {
             AppointmentId = grp.Key,
             AppointmentStatusId = grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.Timestamp)
                                      .FirstOrDefault()
                                      .AppointmentStatusId
    }
);
```

Using the above returns **AppointmentStatusId** status of '1' when first=1/1/2012 and last=2/1/2012.

**Requirements**

I hoped somebody may be able to give me some advice on amending this to meet the following conditions:

- If the most up to date status is within the current period, **include** the record.
- If not, **omit** it from the result set.

Comment: How do you determine if the date status is within the current period?

Comment: @Aducci Using the 'Date' field os the AppointmentStatus table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to move the `last` part of the filtering to after the grouping/winnerpicking.

```
db.AppointmentStatusHistories
.Where(ash => first <= ash.TimeStamp) //omit all records that are before the range
.Where(ash => ash.Appointment.TaskAppointments.Any(ta => ta.Task.Creator == user))
.GroupBy(ash => ash.AppointmentId)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(ash => ash.TimeStamp).First()) //pick a winner
.Where(ash => ash.TimeStamp <= last) //omit winners that are after the range
.Select(ash => new UserAppointmentTargetModel()
{
  AppointmentId = ash.AppointmentId,
  AppoinementStatusId = ash.AppointmentStatus,
  Date = ash.Timestamp
}
```

---

(obligatory query comprehension syntax form of the above)

```
from ash in db.AppointmentStatusHistories
where first <= ash.TimeStamp
where ash.Appointment.TaskAppointments.Any(ta => ta.Task.Creator == user)
group ash by ash.AppointmentId into g
let winner = g.OrderByDescending(ash => ash.TimeStamp).First()
where winner.TimeStamp <= last
select new UserAppointmentTargetModel()
{
  AppointmentId = winner.AppointmentId,
  AppoinementStatusId = winner.AppointmentStatus,
  Date = winner.Timestamp
}
```

---

Side notes:

I used navigation properties to do the user filtering.  If you can't get that to work, go back to the joins.

It's always safe to call First on a Group.  Groups aren't ever empty.  There's no need for FirstOrDefault in this case.

I reused the `ash` variable name in the *method style query* to communicate type since it is declared in two different places where the type is not stated.  I changed that to `winner` in the *comprehension style query* to communicate intent better since it is declared in one place where the type may be verified by inspection.

Also, I never use >= with dates.  It can only lead to sorrow.

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear answer and great explanation. Due to reasons I'll never know, TaskAppointments isn't joined to AppointmentStatusHistories. Where's the most efficient place to join this?

Comment: @Nick I've updated the queries to go through the Appointment property of AppointmentStatusHistories.  It does make sense that two child tables (of Appointment) wouldn't be directly related by navigation properties.